# Questions about the ownership transfer of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

For the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct pm
{
    pm() : a(make_unique<vector<int>>(1, 10)){};
    unique_ptr<vector<int>> a;
};

struct parms
{
    parms() : a(make_unique<pm>()){};
    unique_ptr<pm> a;
};

class test
{
public:
    test() : p(make_unique<parms>()) {}

    unique_ptr<const parms> getParms()
    {
        return move(p);
    }

    void setParms(int b)
    {
        p->a->a->push_back(b);
    }

    void pp()
    {
        cout << p->a->a->at(0) << "\n";
    }

private:
    unique_ptr<parms> p;
};

int main()  
{  
    auto t = make_unique<test>();  
    t->pp();
    cout << t->getParms()->a->a->at(0) << "\n";
    cout << (t->getParms()==nullptr) << "\n";  ;  
}
```

t->getParms() is a nullptr after we "cout << t->getParms()->a->a->at(0) << "\n";".

If we do the same thing for the ptr,

```
int main()  
{  
    auto t = make_unique<test>();  
    t->setParms(5);
    t->pp(); 
    auto ptr = t->getParms();  
    cout << ptr->a->a->at(0) << "\n";  
    cout << (ptr==nullptr) << "\n";  ;  
}
```

ptr is not a nullptr.

My question is: why cout t->getParms(), then t->getParms() is a nullptr but prt is not? Is it because of the life scope of unique_ptr? Or the temporary rvalue? What's the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: When it is returned as a temporary and not stored anywhere, the temporary cleans up after itself at the end of the statement.  When you store it in `ptr`, it is still in that variable later when you look at it again.

Comment: Not sure I follow, `ptr` takes ownership of the pointer which was inside `test`. Future accesses to the field `p` in `test` don't guarantee anything, usually you'll get that it's empty.
It's unusual for a class to "give out" ownership of a field it own.

Comment: Version 1: "Give me your wallet." (look in the wallet, throw the wallet away) "Give me your wallet again (get nothing)." Version 2: "Give me your wallet (look in the wallet, keep the wallet, look in the wallet again)". In the first version, you call `getParms()` twice. Only the first one gives you the params. In the second version, you call `getParms()` only once. That one call gives you the params, which you then use multiple times.

Comment: @Eljay so what you mean is: in fact, in "cout << t->getParms()->a->a->at(0) << "\n";", a temporary is created, the ownership is transferred, then the temporary is destroyed, right?

Comment: @al3c. I understand what you mean. But someone claims the shared_ptr is the last resort; and for my case, I may only need to use the parms once. I am also studying whether unique_ptr or shared_ptr is a better choice.

Comment: `getParams` can return a plain reference, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: `getParms` shouldn't be transferring ownership. It should return a copy of the pointer while the class retains ownership.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, is this a rule? or because the function is getParms() instead of transferParms()?

Comment: Correct, that is what is happening.

Comment: BTW, `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>` is rarely useful, `std::vector<int>` suffices.

Comment: I would rename `getParms()` into `takeParms()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `getParams()` transfers ownership to the caller.

```
unique_ptr<const parms> getParms()
{
    return move(p);
}
```

Member is moved to the return value and now the caller owns the pointee. You are not storing the returned value here:

```
cout << t->getParms()->a->a->at(0) << "\n";
```

Though, even if you did, `t` does not own the `param` anymore, hence when you ask `t` again:

```
cout << (t->getParms()==nullptr) << "\n";  ;
```

It doesnt know about the `param` anymore.

---

In the second example you transfer ownership from `t` to `ptr`:

```
auto ptr = t->getParms();
```

Now `ptr` owns the `param`. And you can inspect the pointer or the  value as often as you like:

```
cout << ptr->a->a->at(0) << "\n";  
cout << (ptr==nullptr) << "\n";  ;
```

There is no transfer of ownership in those two lines.

---

> What's the reason behind this behavior?

The reason, as stated above, is that `getParams()` transfers ownership to the caller. Thats rather uncommon for a getter method. Perhaps "stealer-method" would be a better name ;). If you don't want to give up ownership (and you are certain that the pointer is a valid one) you can simply return a reference:

```
const parms& getParms() const { return *p; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: why cout t->getParms(), then t->getParms() is a nullptr but prt is not?

`t->getParms()` transfers the ownership to the caller. This sets `t->p` to null. Since `t->p` no longer owns a pointer, there is nothing to transfer when you call `t->getParms()` a second time.

You never transferred ownership from `ptr`, so it hasn't been set to null.

Comment: ptr has no getParms(). ptr is the uniqu_ptr<parms>. I think it's because a temporary is created and destroyed.

Comment: @ChuanXu See the fixed answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help.